# Website body background with 3 horizontal colours

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Is there a way to have 3 different horizontal colors of different sizes on a webpage using CSS?

I am creating a webpage for a club and am hoping to make it stand out more with a contrasting white and black background.

I want it to look like this with no fading between colors:

[image: From top to bottom. 15% white, then 50% black then 35% white. The color must cover the entire width of the page.]

I have tried this code. However, the height of the color only covers a small amount of the page.

```
body {
height: 100vh
width: 100vw;    
background-image: linear-gradient(white 10%, black 50%, white 40%);
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0px;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the image you've provided, it seems to be working as expected. The first section of the gradient is white, the middle is black and the third section is white. If you want to make sure the gradient fills the entire page and flows with the viewport, you can use [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

Give the `<body>` a `background-attachment` value of `fixed`. This will make the `background-image` position fixed within the viewport. I updated the [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) usage so the colors don't fade between sections by utilizing color-stop points. This is achieved by defining a starting and ending position for the gradient line. Each section in the gradient doesn't flow into it's neighboring color but shows a sharp distinction between colors.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 10%, green 10% 60%, blue 60%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0px;   
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @rodger Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 65%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Gradient</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

The solution is to mitigate the gradient effect, which is pretty weird since that's what they are used for. We need to tell `linear-gradient` that the black starts exactly after the white ends, and it ends exactly before the white starts.

I usually use this site to design gradients: https://cssgradient.io

It's super neat and contains well-written references and samples.

Answer (score 0):

Add steps to remove color escalation

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        white 0,
        white 10%,
        black 10%,
        black 60%,
        white 60%,
        white 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```